# XAML designer doesn't show Custom Window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2015

I have a WPF window that is inherited from custom window. It runs correctly but VS designer shows it like default empty window instead.

Custom window code:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public class CustomWindow : Window
    {
        public CustomWindow()
        {
            Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }
    }
}
```

`MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<local:CustomWindow x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

</local:CustomWindow>
```

Designer:

[image: Designer]

Expected result:

[image: Expected result]

Comment: You are missing `InitializeComponent()`

Comment: There is no such function because `CustomWindow` class contains no XAML. And it's not possible to inherit class from Windows that contain XAML markup anyway.

Comment: what version/build of VS? What version of Windows?

Comment: VS 2015 (mentioned in tag), Windows 10 (shouldn't matter)

Comment: I'm convinced it's a bug/limitation of the XAML designer. I tried every way I know to set the subclass background (C#, XAML, Themes\Generic.xaml). All work at runtime. None at design time. MahApps.Metro is a theme library. They subclass Window, and they ran into this problem (I chatted with the author).

Answer (score -1):

The XAML designer in both Visual Studio and Blend doesn't necessarily respect any dependency properties that are set directly in code (especially in the constructor), but rather expects those to be set in XAML only, which is the canonical way of working with the dependency system at design time. Of course all things can be set in code if you want, but when using the XAML designer you cannot guarantee the same behaviour as you will see in a running application.
Also, if you are setting dependency properties in code, then you need to be very careful about how you set them, as you may destroy any bindings that may end up being set on those properties.

Anyway, a better way of getting the result you want is to set the color in the XAML like this

```
<local:CustomWindow x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Background="Red">

</local:CustomWindow>
```

Comment: You probably didn't notice that `MainWindow` and `CustomWindow` are 2 different classes. There is no point to have a CustomWindow class if it is empty. I want to have some base window class and inherit all other windows from it. It is not possible to inherit from window that already has XAML code so it *must* be C# only.

Comment: Yes I did notice - of course, but you want a workaround for the XAML designer - and here it is

Comment: And by the way, you can have a custom Window class with its own style and template, so if you're not interested in a simple work-around then try and put in some effort and create your own full implementation

Comment: Moving code from base class to every child class defeats the whole purpose of inheritance. I tried to move this code to separate style too but it doesn't work either because it's not possible to apply this style without code behind.